# Speed up calculation of maximum of normxcorr2

Tags: matlab

I need to calculate the maximum of normalized cross correlation of million of particles. The size of the two parameters of normxcorr2 is 56*56. I can't parallelize the calculations. Is there any suggestion to speed up the code especially that I don't need all the results but only the maximum value of each cross correlation (to know the displacement)?

Example of the algorithm

```
%The choice of 170 particles is because in each time 
%the code detects 170 particles, so over 10000 images it's 1 700 000 particles
particle_1=rand(54,54,170);
particle_2=rand(56,56,170);
for i=1:170
    C=normxcorr2(particle_1(:,:,i),particle_2(:,:,i));
    L(i)=max(C(:));
end
```

Comment: NORMXCORR2 Normalized two-dimensional cross-correlation.
    C = NORMXCORR2(TEMPLATE,A) computes the normalized cross-correlation of
    matrices TEMPLATE and A. The matrix A *must be larger* than the matrix
    TEMPLATE for the normalization to be meaningful.

Comment: Adding `L = zeros(1,170);` in front of the loop for memory preallocation would speed it up a little bit. But yeah, as Jed said, currently there is a conceptual problem too

Comment: @Jed Yes, You are right, I made a mistake on the size, but the problem is still the same

Comment: `normxcorr2` uses FFT in it's implementation, this improves the running time when the images are large. It could be that since your images are small and have similar size then it's better that you implement it yourself in the 'naive' way (iterating the offsets of the template on the image and compute the scalar multiplication for each offset (of course you should also normalize)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have MATLAB so I ran the following code on this site: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_matlab_online.php which is actually octave. So I implemented "naive" normalized cross correlation and indeed for these small images sizes the naive performs better:

Elapsed time is 2.62645 seconds - for `normxcorr2`
Elapsed time is 0.199034 seconds - for my `naive_normxcorr2`

The code is based on the article http://scribblethink.org/Work/nvisionInterface/nip.pdf which describes how to calculate the standard deviation needed for the normalization in an efficient way using [integral image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table), this is the `box_corr` function.

Also, MATLAB's `normxcorr2` returns a padded image so I took the max on the unpadded part.

```
pkg load image

function [N] = naive_corr(pat,img)

[n,m] = size(img);
[np,mp] = size(pat);

 N = zeros(n-np+1,m-mp+1);

 for i = 1:n-np+1
    for j = 1:m-mp+1
        N(i,j) = sum(dot(pat,img(i:i+np-1,j:j+mp-1)));
    end
 end

end


%w_arr the array of coefficients for the boxes
%box_arr of size [k,4] where k is the number boxes, each box represented by
%4 something ... 
function [C] = box_corr2(img,box_arr,w_arr,n_p,m_p)

% construct integral image + zeros pad (for boundary problems)
I = cumsum(cumsum(img,2),1);
I = [zeros(1,size(I,2)+2); [zeros(size(I,1),1) I zeros(size(I,1),1)]; zeros(1,size(I,2)+2)];

% initialize result matrix
[n,m] = size(img);
C = zeros(n-n_p+1,m-m_p+1);
%C = zeros(n,m);

jump_x = 1;
jump_y = 1;

x_start = ceil(n_p/2);
x_end = n-x_start+mod(n_p,2);
x_span = x_start:jump_x:x_end;

y_start = ceil(m_p/2);
y_end = m-y_start+mod(m_p,2);
y_span = y_start:jump_y:y_end;

arr_a = box_arr(:,1) - x_start;
arr_b = box_arr(:,2) - x_start+1;
arr_c = box_arr(:,3) - y_start;
arr_d = box_arr(:,4) - y_start+1;

% cumulate box responses
k = size(box_arr,1); % == numel(w_arr)
for i = 1:k
    a = arr_a(i);
    b = arr_b(i);
    c = arr_c(i);
    d = arr_d(i);

    C = C ...
        + w_arr(i) * ( I(x_span+b,y_span+d) ...
                       - I(x_span+b,y_span+c) ...
                       - I(x_span+a,y_span+d) ...
                       + I(x_span+a,y_span+c) );
end

end



function [NCC]  = naive_normxcorr2(temp,img)

    [n_p,m_p]=size(temp);

    M = n_p*m_p;

    % compute template mean & std
    temp_mean = mean(temp(:));
    temp = temp - temp_mean;

    temp_std = sqrt(sum(temp(:).^2)/M);

    % compute windows' mean & std
    wins_mean =  box_corr2(img,[1,n_p,1,m_p],1/M,  n_p,m_p);
    wins_mean2 = box_corr2(img.^2,[1,n_p,1,m_p],1/M,n_p,m_p);


    wins_std = real(sqrt(wins_mean2 - wins_mean.^2));
    NCC_naive = naive_corr(temp,img);

    NCC = NCC_naive ./ (M .* temp_std .* wins_std);
end 

n = 170;

particle_1=rand(54,54,n);
particle_2=rand(56,56,n);

[n_p1,m_p1,c_p1]=size(particle_1);
[n_p2,m_p2,c_p2]=size(particle_2);

L1 = zeros(n,1);
L2 = zeros (n,1);

tic
for i=1:n
    C1=normxcorr2(particle_1(:,:,i),particle_2(:,:,i));

    C1_unpadded = C1(n_p1:n_p2 , m_p1:m_p2);
    L1(i)=max(C1_unpadded(:));

end

toc

tic
for i=1:n

    C2=naive_normxcorr2(particle_1(:,:,i),particle_2(:,:,i));
    L2(i)=max(C2(:));
end

toc
```

Comment: Another thing, since you only need the maxes and not the whole NCC, with the naive implementation you can decide for a threshold for the max value.  During the iteration of the naive implementation, once you get a value that meets the threshold you can stop. If the threshold is good  then you could assume that the first location you found is the max. It might not always succeed but most of the time.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Finally, I did also the same thing by calculating cross correlation only on the part that interests me. It made big speed up ( factor of 10 for a region 5x5 )